# Reorganize/Rebuild single index vs all table indexes

Tags: sql-server

We are planning to run index rebuild/reorganize on a regular basis in our application.

We are aware that we should reorganize when index fragmentation goes over 5% and rebuild when it is over 30%.

We are just wondering whether we shall reorganize/rebuild:

- only particular index which is fragmented on a table (ALTER INDEX {name} ON ...)
- all indexes on a table (ALTER INDEX ALL ON ...) if there is at least one index fragmented

Which approach do you find better?

Comment: I think first option is better

Comment: Thanks @Prdp. Can you give an explanation why? From logical point of view it seems better to me too (reorganize only what's wrong and leave others as they are), but it would be great to confirm it with some MS best practices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why SQL Server doesn't have anything inbuilt for such operations, but I have recently used a script written by `Ola Hallengren` for Index maintenance , and I have to say it is the most beautiful piece of code I have come across and also which is free.

The scripts has some cool features like.

1. It is compatible with all versions of SQL Server 2005 , 2008 , 2012 , 2014 and 2016.
2. It reorgs indexes when fragmentation is below 30% else it rebuild the index. You can also change this threshold via parameters.
3. It checks the SQL Server licences, if Enterprise it will rebuild the index online else it rebuilds it offline.

I mean the list goes on, its definitely worth checking.

You can get the scripts from here [`SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance" by Ola Hallengren"`](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)